# How to animate background-image transition?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image

I am adding a class to a div that changes the background image:

```
$('div').addClass('specialBackground');
```

The problem is that this effect is rather jarring. I would like to fade between the different background images, and hopefully keep this css in my stylesheet. How can I achieve this?

Comment: can we see the markup and css?

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look here for an example](http://jsfiddle.net/Diodeus/gYyBL/).

A fade effect will work by putting an image over the background and changing its opacity.

Comment: Might want to consider using data-hover-image instead of adding a non existing attribute hoverImage

Comment: What difference would this make?

Comment: It will keep your page w3c valid

Comment: Data attributes can be used prior to html 5 also. It's just a good practice to use them, rather than making up attributes that don't really exist.